# Cordova 3.0 plugin, Class not found

Tags: android, plugins, cordova, config

I'm trying to create a plugin for Cordova 3.0 on Android with the Echo example but it's not working.

I added `<plugin name="MMSSender" value="my.package.mms.MMSSender" />` to my `config.xml` (from `www` and did `cordova build`)

Then I created a new Class MMSSender in `my.package.mms` with the example code given ;

```
package my.package.mms;

import org.apache.cordova.api.CordovaPlugin;
import org.apache.cordova.api.PluginResult;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;


public class Echo extends CordovaPlugin {
    @Override
    public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args, CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {
        if (action.equals("echo")) {
            String message = args.getString(0); 
            this.echo(message, callbackContext);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private void echo(String message, CallbackContext callbackContext) {
        if (message != null && message.length() > 0) { 
            callbackContext.success(message);
        } else {
            callbackContext.error("Expected one non-empty string argument.");
        }
    }
}
```

And I added the code below the my main js file. **Edit :** the code in wrapped in `deviceready` event

```
window.echo = function(str, callback) {
    cordova.exec(callback, function(err) {
        callback(err);
    }, "MMSSender", "echo", [str]);
};

window.echo("echome", function(echoValue) {
    alert(echoValue);
});
```

The problem is that echoValue contains "Class not found".

Any idea ?
Do I have to modify the `plugins` folder ?

Comment: your class name is "echo", should it be "MMSSender"?

Comment: If you could post the Plugin.xml We can check for errors if any.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Usually you prepare a separate package with a plugin.xml file, java class and js file and then add it to the app using the `cordova plugin add` command.

Anyway, one thing you may miss is the link between the name of the parameter of the cordova.exec function and your plugin class.

You should modifiy the file `res/xml/config.xml` and add lines like this :

```
<feature name="MMSSender">
    <param name="android-package" value="my.package.mms.MMSSender" />
</feature>
```

### EDIT:

---

In your repo, you need to correct the imports in MMS.java:

replace

```
import org.apache.cordova.api.CordovaPlugin;
import org.apache.cordova.api.PluginResult;
```

with

```
import org.apache.cordova.CordovaPlugin;
import org.apache.cordova.CallbackContext;
```

Once that corrected, you should be able at least to build the project.

Comment: Thanks for the anwser, but as I'm using Cordova, I can't modify res/xml/config.xml because it's rewritten on each build :/. EDIT : It's not working even if I modify this file (without building)

Comment: that's why I said this should be done in plugin.xml and the plugin added by cordova plugin add. And the update of config.xml should be done with a "config-file" tag inside plugin.xml.

Comment: Ok I see. I'll try it. The command line will be `cordova plugin add my.package.mms` ?

Comment: usually it's followed by the url of a git repo. When I test my plugins I use it with the path of the folder on my computer. Look at cordova's core api plugins for examples of plugin structure.

Comment: I've tried to create the plugin but an error occurs during the build, it's `ant`. Don't know what to do. Here is the plugin : [gitrepo](https://github.com/thomashiron/PluginMMS.git)

Comment: The build works now (`CallbackContext` wasn't import). Now I get `Property 'mms' of object [object global] is not a function`

Answer (score 0):

Import your phonegap(Cordova) project into your IDE (Eclipse + ADT) as an existing android project. Then you will see what is wrong with your plugin java code. In my case the problem was wrong package name and it resulted in class not found message from javascript callback.