# cordova.exec error Class not found

Tags: java, javascript, cordova

I'm attempting to write a plugin for phonegap that will access native Java that I have written.  The only problem is that when I call cordova.exec, the failure callback message is "Class not found".  I'm assuming this means that it can't find the java file, but I don't know why.

Here is my code.
Javascript:

```
var SerialHelper = {
        getName: function(){
            return "this is the name"
        },
    getSerial: function(success, failure) {
         cordova.exec(
           success, // success callback function
           failure, // error callback function
           'com.isabellaproducts.serialhelper.SerialHelper',
           'getFableSerial',
           []
        );
    }
}
module.exports = SerialHelper;
```

Java:

```
package com.isabellaproducs.serialhelper;

import org.apache.cordova.CallbackContext;
import org.apache.cordova.CordovaPlugin;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.apache.cordova.*;


public class SerialHelper extends CordovaPlugin
{

    @Override
    public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args, CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {

        if ("getFableSerial".equals(action)) {
            String serial = "15345344132354";
            callbackContext.success(serial);
            //callbackContext.sendPluginResult(new PluginResult(Status.OK, serial));
            return true;
        }
        else{
            callbackContext.error("method not found");
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

plugin.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<plugin xmlns="http://www.phonegap.com/ns/plugins/1.0"
           id="com.isabellaproducts.serialhelper"
      version="1.0">
    <name>SerialHelper</name>
    <description>Serial Helper gets the Fable gives serial number access</description>
    <license>MIT</license>
    <keywords>serial, helper, fable</keywords>


    <js-module src="www/serial_helper.js" name="SerialHelper">
        <clobbers target="com.isabellaproducts.serialhelper" />
    </js-module>

    <!-- android -->
    <platform name="android">
        <source-file src="src/android/com/isabellaproducts/serialhelper/SerialHelper.java" target-dir="src/com/isabellaproducts/serialhelper" /> 

        <config-file target="res/xml/config.xml" parent="/*">
            <feature name="SerialHelper">
                <param name="android-package" value="com.isabellaproducts.serialhelper.SerialHelper"/>
            </feature>
        </config-file>

     </platform>          
</plugin>
```

In logcat, I get this error:

```
D/PluginManager(12316): exec() call to unknown plugin: SerialHelper
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: This issue sounds similiar to yours

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21737267/cordova-3-0-plugin-class-not-found

Comment: You are right, but unfortunately, I have already seen that one.  It hasn't helped yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wow....so, I was putting the plugin in a custom package.  That was messing everything up!

The simple change from:
**com.isabellaproducts.serialhelper** 
to 
**com.phonegap.plugins.serialhlper**

It now looks like this.
Javascript:

```
var SerialHelper = {
        getName: function(){
            return "this is the name"
        },
    getSerial: function(success, failure) {
         cordova.exec(
           success, // success callback function
           failure, // error callback function
           'SerialHelper',
           'getFableSerial',
           []
        );
    }
}
module.exports = SerialHelper;
```

Java:

```
package com.phonegap.plugins.serialhelper;

import org.apache.cordova.CallbackContext;
import org.apache.cordova.CordovaPlugin;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.apache.cordova.*;


public class SerialHelper extends CordovaPlugin
{

    @Override
    public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args, CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {

        if ("getFableSerial".equals(action)) {
            String serial = "15345344132354";
            callbackContext.success(serial);
            //callbackContext.sendPluginResult(new PluginResult(Status.OK, serial));
            return true;
        }
        else{
            callbackContext.error("method not found");
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

plugin.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<plugin xmlns="http://www.phonegap.com/ns/plugins/1.0"
           id="com.phonegap.plugins.serialhelper"
      version="1.0">
    <name>SerialHelper</name>
    <description>Serial Helper gets the Fable gives serial number access</description>
    <license>MIT</license>
    <keywords>serial, helper, fable</keywords>


    <js-module src="www/serial_helper.js" name="SerialHelper">
        <clobbers target="com.phonegap.plugins.serialhelper" />
    </js-module>

    <!-- android -->
    <platform name="android">
        <source-file src="src/android/com/phonegap/plugins/serialhelper/SerialHelper.java" target-dir="src/com/phonegap/plugins/serialhelper" /> 

        <config-file target="res/xml/config.xml" parent="/*">
            <feature name="SerialHelper">
                <param name="android-package" value="com.phonegap.plugins.serialhelper.SerialHelper"/>
            </feature>
        </config-file>

     </platform>          
</plugin>
```